# foreach until find some value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a code that get categories from database but I don't know how to get all subcategories(parents).

This my php code :

```
function get_the_category($allCats,$filter_id = null) {

$re_struct_cat = array();
$filter_id =  10;
$ids = array();
$xx = array();
foreach($allCats as $cat_key=>$cat_val) {
    $re_struct_cat[$cat_val["id"]] = array(
        "title" => $cat_val["cat_title"],
        "parent" => $cat_val["cat_parent"],
    );

$ids = array_merge($ids,array($cat_val["id"]));
}

foreach($ids as $k=>$v) {
    if($re_struct_cat[$v]["parent"]) {
        $xx[] = $re_struct_cat[$re_struct_cat[$v]["parent"]];
    }
}

return $xx;
//return $re_struct_cat;

//print_r($re_struct_cat);
}
```

What I want exactly

I have table with 3 columns [id,title,parent]

```
ID      TITLE       PARENT
1       Science     0
2       Math        1
3       Algebra     2
4       Analyse     2
5       Functions   4
```

So if variable `filter_id = 10` I got `cat_parent = 4` 
So I want to take that value and looking for it in array and if find another cat_parent do the same thing until find 0 or null value

Comment: You have `$filter_id =  10` but you never use it.

Comment: @ryantxr it's can be null because I want to get all categories and their info and I want to get specift category info and parent

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most optimal solution, but you can use [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php).

Firstly, create the custom iterator, that can handle categories:

```
class AdjacencyListIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
{
    private $adjacencyList;

    public function __construct(
        array $adjacencyList,
        array $array = null,
        $flags = 0
    ) {
        $this->adjacencyList = $adjacencyList;

        $array = !is_null($array)
            ? $array
            : array_filter($adjacencyList, function ($node) {
                return is_null($node['parent']);
            });

        parent::__construct($array, $flags);
    }

    private $children;

    public function hasChildren()
    {
        $children = array_filter($this->adjacencyList, function ($node) {
            return $node['parent'] === $this->current()['id'];
        });

        if (!empty($children)) {
            $this->children = $children;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new static($this->adjacencyList, $this->children);
    }
}
```

It is taken from my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749208/traversing-hierarchy-tree-adjacency-list-model-in-yii2/45753017#45753017).

Then you can simply loop over this iterator until you find the needed id:

```
$id = 5;
$categories = [];
$result = null;
foreach ($iterator as $node) {
    $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
    $categories[$depth] = $node['categoryname'];

    if ($node['id'] === $id) {
        $result = array_slice($categories, 0, $depth + 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/754ffb87878e7f88a6e491e047d8a9ccdd6d7dc6).

Comment: thank you so much from your answer. but I know this solution :(
If you know can you just explain to me how wordpress do this. thank you again for your time

Comment: @oxmixpro, unfortunately, I have never worked with WordPress, so I do not know how they do it myself.

Comment: @oxmixpro you should probably give all the context for what you need in your question. That would prevent people from wasting their time trying to help you.